# Add multipe text box inputs into an SQL database as a new record

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I am using this code to add more text boxes into a form. Basically, I am allowing it so users can add multiple languages that they speak.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var i = 0;
    $('#theButton').click(addAnotherTextBox);
    function addAnotherTextBox() {
        $("#theForm").append("<br><label>Language <input type='text' name='language" + i + "' >");
    }
});
</script>


<div id='theForm'></div>
<form id="form" name="form">
   <input id='theButton' type='button' value='Add Medical History'>
   <input id="submit" onclick="myFunctionlanguage()" type="button" 
value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >
</form>
```

the function on the submit button basically post's the data it collects into a PHP file using ajax (So that it does not need to direct to another page or refresh in order to post it.

The PHP code I currently have is

```
$language = $_POST['language'];    
if (isset($_POST['language1'])) {
    $sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `languages` (`language`,`cc`,`userid`)
VALUES('$language','cc','$user->id')";
    mysql_query($sql_insert1) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
}
```

This does not seem to be adding each language I've typed in once I add a new text box.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : - I've tried the examples below and it still does not seem to be adding into my database.

Could it be something to do with my actual on click function?

```
<script>
 function myFunctionlanguage() {
    var language = document.getElementById("location").value;       
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = '&language1=' + language;
    if (location == '') {
        alert("Please enter a language!");
    } else {
        // AJAX code to submit form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/updatelanguage.php?userid=<?echo $user->id;?>",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
                document.getElementById('close').click()
                window.location.reload();
            }   
    });
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of using `language+i` you could use `language[]` this will create an array in `$_POST`. If you want to store this as a string in database then you have to use `implode()` before storing it. If you want to add an entry for each language you will have to use `foreach()`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. 
As I am getting you, it may be useful for you.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

$('#theButton').click(addAnotherTextBox);
function addAnotherTextBox() {
var i=parseInt($("#max").val());
i=i+1;
$("#max").val(i);
$("#form").prepend("<br><label>Language <input type='text' name='language" + i + "' >");
}
});

</script>

<form id="form" name="form">
<input type="hidden" name='max' id="max" value="0"/>
<input id='theButton' type='button' value='Add Medical History'>
<input id="submit" onclick="myFunctionlanguage()" type="button" 
value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ></form>



$max=$_POST['max'];

for($i=1;$i<=$max;$i++){

$language = $_POST['language'.$i];


if (isset($_POST['language'.$i])) {

$sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `languages`
(`language`,`cc`,`userid`)
VALUES('$language','cc','$user->id')";


mysql_query($sql_insert1) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to dynamically assign a name to each input box, you should just name them all `languages[]`, which will let you post all the input boxes with the name `languages[]` as one single variable of the `$POST` array.

HTML:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#theButton').click(addAnotherTextBox);
    function addAnotherTextBox() {
        $("#theForm").append("<br><label>Language <input type='text' name='languages[]' >");
    }
});

</script>

<div id='theForm'></div>
<form id="form" name="form">
<input id='theButton' type='button' value='Add Medical History'>
<input id="submit" onclick="myFunctionlanguage()" type="button" 
value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ></form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['languages'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['languages'] as $language) {}
        $sql_insert1 = "INSERT into `languages` (`language`,`cc`,`userid`) VALUES ('$language','cc','$user->id')";

        mysql_query($sql_insert1) or die("Insertion Failed:" . mysql_error());
    }
}
```